# Understanding GraphQL

Tags: api, graphql

I started experimenting with the GraphQL wp api.

I am querying the menus. As for the documentation, the query is very long

I would expect that querying

```
{
    menus
}
```

only would bring about all the data nested in menus, it does not.

Why is this? What is the way to getting all nested data in an object as to see what's in there?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the **main** feature of `GraphQL`, you can specify what data you need from a query. And because of that, you can't just query menus in that way, you need to specify **every** nested field in menus you need and only then it'll work :)

Comment: What if I don't know them all? What if I do and want them all? Why is not "empty" equal to "all" by default? Shouldn't that be a feature? What if is the nesting is complicated?

Comment: You know what, it made me think about it again, and I thought what if you can query one field which will return you a json string and then you just decode it. Although, it's kinda silly because you lose all the benefits that `GQL` gives you. And as strange, as it sounds: How can you use fields you don't even know about? If you do know, just specify all of them and return fields that are present. If it's complicated - make it simpler, use flat and not nested structures. But as always, it all depends on context and overall goal, you might even end up not using `GQL` at some point :)

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. You could want to use properties that you don't know about looping through all properties but it's probably something that never actually happens, that you have to do that.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is that every "leaf" fields in a GraphQL query should be a [`Scalar`](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types) something like `Int` , `Boolean` , `String` etc.  So if the `meuns` field in the root `Query` type is a `Scalar` , it is a valid query and will return you something.

If not , you have to continue navigating the `Menu` type and pick the fields that you want to include in the GraphQL query such as :

```
{
   menus {
     id
     createdDate
  }
}
```

There is no wildcard that can represent all fields in current GraphQL spec.You have to explicitly declare all fields you want to select in the query.By looking at the GraphQL schema, you can know the available fields for each type. One of the tips is to rely on the GraphQL [introspection system](https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/) .It basically means that you can use some of the GraphQL client such as [Altair](https://altair.sirmuel.design/), [Graphiql](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql), or [GraphQL Playground](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-playground) etc. which most of them will have some auto-suggest function that will guide you to compose a query by suggesting you what fields are available to be included for a type .

*P.S. A similar analogy to SQL is that there is no `select * from foo` , you have to explicitly define the columns that you want to select in the select clause such as `select id,name,address from foo`.*

Comment: I understand, but I am really turned down by this. It would be a logical feature

Comment: A "wildcard" syntax makes no sense in GraphQL for a number of reasons. 1) Possible fields could include arguments -- if that were the case, it would be impossible to infer what values should be passed to the arguments to resolve the fields. 2) Fields are closer to functions than just properties of an object -- how do you get "all the fields" when each field could take any number of arguments? 3) Fields could include recursive references -- i.e. `{ posts { author { posts { author { ... } } } } }` -- it's not possible to infer to what depth we should query the graph when asking for "all fields".

Answer (score 2):

If you keep in mind that you're getting back a JSON object, you can think of your GraphQL query as defining the left-hand side of the response (this is intentional in how it was designed), e.g. just the keys. So unless there are null values, what you get back should exactly match the shape of the query.

If you want to see what *can* be queried, you need access to the schema itself. If it's a schema provided by someone else (looks like WordPress in this case), they should also have provided the means to explore and understand it.